# Minimum of $x^x$

Tags: analysis, exponential-function

So the title says almost everything.

> Why is the minimum of the function $x\mapsto x^x$ exactly at $x= e^{-1}$?

Don't get me wrong. I am able to write $x^x$ as $\exp(x \ln(x))$ myself and can differentiate $x^x$ to conclude that the minimum lies at $x=e^{-1}$.

However, since $x^x$ can be defined without the $e$-function I guess  there has to be another explaination which hopefully gives more insight.

Comment: $x^x = e^{x\log(x)}$ so the minimum of $x^x$ corresponds to the minimum of $f(x) = x\log(x)$. Solving $f'(x) = 0$ gives you the solution.

Comment: How can we define $x^x$ without the $e$ function, maybe as a solution of an functional equation or a differential equation, but I don't know could you define it

Comment: how is $x^x$ defined without the natural exponential function?

Comment: It has been explained in the comments to the first answer, how $x^x$ can be defined without the exponential function.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to study the extrema of the function $x^y$ subjected to the condition $x-y=0$ using the method of Langrange multipliers.

Comment: Of course not: in order to get the partial derivatives of $x^y$ you don't need to resort to any trick involving the exponential. $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} = y x^{y-1}$ and $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} = x^y \log x$.

Comment: But how do you define $x^y$ without the exponential?

Comment: You first construct the real numbers. Next, you define $x^n$ for $n \in \mathrm{N}$, next $x^n$ for $n \in \mathrm{Z}$, then $x^q$ for $q \in \mathrm{Q}$ - all these purely algebraically. Then, for $y \in \mathrm{R}$ choose some sequence $(q_n)_{n \in \mathrm{N}} \subset \mathrm{Q}$ such that $q_n \to y$, define $x^y$ as $\lim \space x^{q_n}$ and finally prove that this definition does not depend on the chosen sequence, but only on its equivalence class as a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Anyway, the OP said that he knows how to define $x^x$ without the exponential, so that's how one also defines $x^y$.

Comment: Alex, you are right. Have you calculated your approach explicitly and concluded that the minimum has to be at $x=1/e$.? (I am a little bit lazy :-)

Comment: @AlexM : then you also need to prove the formulas for the nice partials derivative you gave us.